# How can I dynamically call constant values?

Tags: ios, objective-c, dynamic, constants, c-preprocessor

I want to define a lot of constant and irregular value like the following:

```
#define LEVEL_01 2.0f
#define LEVEL_02 3.0f
#define LEVEL_03 5.0f
#define LEVEL_04 8.5f
#define LEVEL_05 10.0f
#define LEVEL_06 15.0f
```

How can I get the value dynamically?

I.e.

```
int n ;
float = <NSString stringWithFormat:@"LEVEL_%.2i", n>;
```

Can I do it well? Or any other effective usage of Objective-C?

Comment: Re: Actually, I am weak in the basic of C programming. That's why I raise a question that I don't know here. And I have ask other way to perform what I need. If you know, please give me some suggestion ok?

Comment: At the very beginning: Why do you need such defines? Obviously a level index is an integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use predefined constant values instead of preprocessor definitions. One of the many reasons to do so is --- Preprocessor definitions are NOT dynamic, and they are not even "static code". They are merely text-replacement commands to the C/C++ preprocessor that manipulates your C source BEFORE the compiler comes in.

The C/C++ compiler never even knows of your LEVEL_0X constants. it only sees their evaluation

```
float a = 2.0f;
```

Instead, you should declare and define an immutable variables containing the values

```
const float LEVEL_01 = 2.0f;
const float LEVEL_02 = 3.0f;
const float LEVEL_03 = 5.0f;
const float LEVEL_04 = 8.5f;
const float LEVEL_05 = 10.0f;
const float LEVEL_06 = 15.0f;
```

and use them instead. This is of course a "C" style solution. You might want something more elegant and high-level that can be used for abstractions in Objective-C. Then I would recommend an immutable NSDictionary of immutable NSNumbers.

```
NSDictionary *levels = @[@"LEVEL_01":@(2.0f), 
                        @"LEVEL_02":@(3.0f),
                        @"LEVEL_03":@(5.0f),
                        @"LEVEL_04":@(8.5.0f),
                        @"LEVEL_05":@(10.0f),
                        @"LEVEL_06":@(15.0f)};
```

and later get them as

```
float val2 = levels[@"LEVEL_02"].floatValue;
```

You could also go the Enum path, to declare your levels by name (but no with float values) or jump on the new Swift carriage, and forget about preprocessor on the first place, and have strongly typed enumerated values of any type.

Comment: Thank you for your details explaination. you are very nice guy. thank you

Answer (score 1):

no you can't get the #define values dynamically. at least not directly, you could create an array with these values and access them:

```
NSArray *levelData = @[ @(LEVEL_01), @(LEVEL_02), @(LEVEL_03), @(LEVEL_04), @(LEVEL_05), @(LEVEL_06) ];

int n = 2;
float currentValue = [levelData[n] floatValue]
```